# Subsampling an unbalanced dataset in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Tensorflow beginner here. This is my first project and I am working with pre-defined estimators.

I have an extremely unbalanced dataset where positive outcomes represent roughly 0.1% of the total data and I suspect this imbalance to considerably affect the performance of my model. As a first attempt to solve the issue, since I have tons of data, I would like to throw away most of my negatives in order to create a balanced dataset. I can see two ways of doing it: preprocess the data to keep only a thousandth of the negatives then save it in a new file before passing it to tensorflow, for example with pyspark; and asking tensorflow to use only one negative out of a thousand it finds.

I tried to code this last idea but didn't manage. I modified my input function to read like

```
def train_input_fn(data_file="../data/train_input.csv", shuffle_size=100_000, batch_size=128):
    """Generate an input function for the Estimator."""

    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(data_file)  # Extract lines from input files using the Dataset API.
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_csv, num_parallel_calls=3)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_size).repeat().batch(batch_size)

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()

    # TRY TO IMPLEMENT THE SELECTION OF NEGATIVES
    thrown = 0
    flag = np.random.randint(1000)
    while labels == 0 and flag != 0:
        features, labels = iterator.get_next()
        thrown += 1
        flag = np.random.randint(1000)
    print("I've thrown away {} negative examples before going for label {}!".format(thrown, labels))
    return features, labels
```

This, of course, doesn't work because iterators don't know what's inside them, so the labels==0 condition is never satisfied. Also, there is only one print in the stdout, meaning that this function is only called once (and meaning that I still don't understand how tensorflow really works). Anyways, is there a way to implement what I want?

PS: I suspect that the previous code, even if it worked as intended, would return less than a thousandth of the initial negatives due to the count restarting every time it finds a positive. This is a minor issue, and so far I could even find a magic number inside the flag that gives me the expected result without worrying too much about the mathematical beauty of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably get better results by *oversampling* your under-represented class rather than throwing away data in your over-represented class. This way you keep the variance in the over-represented class. You might as well use the data you have.

The easiest way to achieve this is probably to create two Datasets, one for each class. Then you can use `Dataset.interleave` to sample equally from both datasets.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. One thing is not clear to me about `Dataset.interleave`: I have to create two separate files, one with positive outcomes and one with negative ones, right?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable way to go, it's not necessary though. You need to start by creating two separate Dataset objects, one for each of the classes. How you do that is up to you. Separate files sounds easy, but you could probably work out a way to filter out the unwanted class from each Dataset. `Dataset.interleave` requires that you pass in multiple datasets and it simply samples one value from each in turn and returns that as its own dataset. Hence it does the work of balancing the classes automatically. Make sure to add `.shuffle` to each of the per-class datasets individually.

Answer (score 0):

Oversampling can be easily achieved with following code:

```
resampled_ds = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets([pos_ds, neg_ds], weights=[0.7, 0.3])
```

Tensorflow has a good guide on dealing with unbalanced data you can find more ideas here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#oversampling